# Can I remove the ENS subdomain from an Aragon DAO?

Tags: solidity, ens, dao, eth-domain

I am new to the DAO creation world!! I am building a platform to launch projects developed by DAOs, the platform is going to create lot of DAOs... if every DAO get an ens name, isn't it going to pollute the dao.eth domain? Can we "delete daos" and release unused subdomain? what is the policy concerning dao creations?

Answer (score 0):

ENS domains are assigned to DAO's on creation, but they are designed to be intentionally immutable.

Otherwise, this would open the door to massive subdomain squatting or even DAO's selling their ENS to an attacker and all of a sudden, people realizing that they sent money to the wrong address.

Unassigning them could be tricky because of this. If adidas.dao.eth is paid to release its domain so that somebody else can claim it immediately, this opens the door to confusion, fraud or scam.

If you need to create many DAOs for which you don't want a domain, you can simply enter an empty subdomain and nothing will be assigned. You will be able to use the DAO by its public address and that's it.